# Преобразование чисел в строки и обратно

Tags: java, android

хотел бы узнать ваше мнение.

Начал изучать джава, и во всех курсах во всех книгах прописано что нужно создавать класс, потом метод и потом описание метода.

Тогда как понять вот такие советы на этом и других форумах)))

```
        double a = (doppoint1.getText() == null) ? 0 : Double.parseDouble(doppoint1.getText().toString());
        double b = (doppoint2.getText() == null) ? 0 : Double.parseDouble(doppoint2.getText().toString());
        point4.setText (String.valueOf (a * b));
```

Насколько я понял мы создаем переменную вdouble a,b и в этом коде прописываем if-else c помощью тернарного оператора ?.
Немного пробывал модифицировать под свое приложение
как понимаю создается 2 переменные, которые которые приравнивают doppoint1 и doppoint2 к null(то есть к пустоте) если в строке ничего нет то выполняется 0, если туда введут что то, то выполняется второй алгоритм после :
String.valueOf (a * b) по идее эта комбинация должна преобразовать дабл значение в строку и поместить в другой эдит.

Короче вопрос такой, почему такие коды не обернуты в класс и метод? или метод onCreate является главным и его достаточно?

И да при запуске приложения из за этого кода лаяут крашится просто(((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это неверный код. `getText` не возвращает `null`. Тут, скорее, `Double.parseDouble` нужно обернуть в `try-catch`, т.к. в EditText может быть не введено число.

Что-то вроде такого:

```
static double stringToDouble(String s) {
    try {
      return Double.parseDouble(s);
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e)
    {
      return 0;
    }
```

```
double a = stringToDouble(doppoint1.getText().toString())
double b = stringToDouble(doppoint2.getText().toString())
point4.setText(String.valueOf (a * b));
```

Если отвечать на ваш вопрос про оборачивание в классы и методы, то в Java по сути почти любой значимый код находится в каком-то методе, а метод внутри класса. Не нужно пытаться оборачивать каждую строчку кода в отдельный метод. Исходите их соображений удобства. Выделяйте отдельные куски кода, которые решают обособленную подзадачу. Методы позволяют избежать повторов в коде. В примере выше я бы мог не писать метод `stringToDouble`, а дважды использовать конструкцию `try-catch`, но тогда бы код стал более громоздким. Учитывайте  также удобство чтения. Считается, что тело метода должно умещаться примерно на одном экране компьютера без прокрутки. Если это не так для какого-то метода, лучше его разбить на несколько методов.

Comment: static double stringToDouble(String s)
я же праильно понимаю это типо if else, try проверяет на наличие ошибок, если есть ошибка выполняется catch?
stringToDouble(String s)=stringToDouble а имя метода получается равно вот так? просто не могу запомнить никак string[] args для чего нужен, везде написано но не понятно зачем оно)))

Comment: https://www.examclouds.com/ru/java/java-core-russian/argumenti-komandnoy-stroki

Comment: `try-catch` — это обработчик исключений. Да, если выбросит исключение `NumberFormatException`, то выполнится `catch`. Вам что-то непонятно из моего ответа?